# Creating a login session to a webpage

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8, authentication

I hope I ask in the correct way in here as it is my first in stackoverflow.
I am pretty new in C# and WP8, but I am working on a small project where I through my WP8 app login to my page and then my wish is to be able to, after the login, to somehow use the session/cookie from the login to navigate in a WebBrowser control through the other "protected" pages.
I have indeed searched the forums and the net, but I have not found the specific answer elsewhere.
Below I have my login session which works and "result" gives me the HTML of the page after login. But then I am a bit stuck...
Maybe there is a better/smarter/easier way?

Best Regards
Martin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using HTTPPost.Resources;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HTTPPost
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri("http://homepage.com/index.php");
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

        // Create the post data
        string postData = "user=usernamepass=password";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }

    void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result;
            result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            MiniBrowser.NavigateToString(result);
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is lots of answers about getting and storing cookies, but I have a trick to avoid using them. The trick is to use same instance of WebClient for all requests on this page after login sequence. See my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeApp
{
    public class WebRequests
    {
        //Making property of HttpClient
        private static HttpClient _client;

        public static HttpClient Client
        {
            get { return _client; }
            set { _client = value; }
        }
        //method to download string from page
        public static async Task<string> LoadPageAsync(string p)
        {
            if (Client == null)// that means we need to login to page
            {
                Client = await Login(Client);
            }
            return await Client.GetStringAsync(p);

        }
        // method for logging in
        public static async Task<HttpClient> Login(HttpClient client)
        {
            client = new HttpClient();

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "someone@example.com"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "SoMePasSwOrD")
                });

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.website.com/login.php", content);
            return client;
        }

        var page1Html = await LoadPageAsync("https://www.website.com/page1.php");


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rovshan. Forgive me for not answering your answer. I was occupied with another App and forgot about this one. I must say that your suggested solution works brilliantly and I used it as described! Thank you very much! Best Regards Martin